# ScheduledExecutorService does not end thread like Timer

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, scheduledexecutorservice

I have 2 snippets of codes, one uses ScheduledExecutorService to execute a Thread at a certain time, the other uses Timer to execute a TimerTask at a certain time. The problem is while using ScheduledExecutorService, even though the thread's run() reaches the end, a monitor program indicates that it is still alive (see image bellow). The TimerTask, on the other hand, ends its thread once the execution is completed.

I have changed ScheduledExecutorService's Thread to TimerTask but received the same result. How do I resolve the issue while using ScheduledExecutorService?

**Timer:**

```
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            System.out.println("doing something");
        }
    };

    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(task, 250);
```

[image: Thread count while using Timer]

**ScheduledExecutorService:**

```
    Thread task = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {               
            System.out.println("doing something");
        }
    };

    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    scheduler.schedule(task, 250, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

[image: Thread count while using ScheduledExecutorService]

Comment: You don't submit threads to an executor service, you submit runnables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second snippet, you've created a `Thread` instance but the `ScheduledExecutorService` has used the instance as a `Runnable`, ie. it only cares about its `run` method. It doesn't actually `start` the `Thread`.

`ScheduledExecutorService` maintains its own `Thread`(s) for executing tasks. With `newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor`, this is a single non-daemon `Thread`. You'll need to `shutdown` the `ScheduledExecutorService` for that `Thread` to complete.

The [javadoc of `Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) states

> After the last live reference to a `Timer` object goes away and all
>   outstanding tasks have completed execution, the timer's task execution
>   thread terminates gracefully (and becomes subject to garbage
>   collection).

After it has executed your `TimerTask`, it will complete its internal thread.

Comment: I added `scheduler.shutdown()` to the end of `run()` and it worked. However, the reason I used Thread is to implement `thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(uncaughtExceptionHandler)`, since `ScheduledExecutorService` uses its own thread, `setUncaughtExceptionHandler` therefore produces no effect? Is there anyway I can get access the ScheduledExecutorService's Thread and set its `UncaughtExceptionHandler`?

Comment: @user945711 That wouldn't work. A `Thread`'s `uncaughtExceptionHandler` is only actually used by the thread created for that `Thread` object.

Comment: @user945711 `schedule` gives you back a `Future`. You can handle your exception there.

Comment: `Future` and `ScheduledFuture` don't seem to have anything similar to `Thread`'s `UncaughtExceptionHandler`. Is there any alternative?

Comment: @user945711 No, you'd handle the exception explicitly by calling `get` on them. You can pass a `ThreadFactory` to the overloaded `newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor` method. You'd set an `uncaughtExceptionHandler` on the threads it returns. However, `ScheduledExecutorService`(s) actually do handle the exception, by completing the `Future` with it, so that won't work for you. This group of class just isn't built for that.